# Is it possible to pass a value to php from a Mysql trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, triggers

I am using phpmyadmin and i am having a trigger which executes after inserting some entries in a table,in that trigger i call a php file.But i need to pass a value to php file from trigger.. is it possible? if so suggest me some code for how to pass it.(the value is something a new value inserted in the table) Help Me.Thanks!

Comment: no. an insert query cannot "return" any data, therefore any trigger executed as part of that insert cannot "return" anything either.

Comment: @Marc B the data value is something like 'new.a' where 'a' is a column name in the table

Comment: yes, but that's only usable inside the trigger. it is NOT possible for an `insert` to return data as if it was a `select` query.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert with phpmyadmin but let's say you call your php file with the trigger like so:

```
dosomething.php
```

You can pass `$_GET` variable like so:

```
dosomething.php?username=john
```

You could then access this variable within the dosomething.php like so:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

If you would

> echo $username;

it would return `john`

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can not return data, but it can change the values of newly inserted or updated records (if it's a `BEFORE` trigger), and can change other tables as well.

So you can create a logging table, write some data there in a trigger (linking them to the newly inserted record somehow), then read that data from `PHP` in a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it's possible** - using session variable with disabled autocommit.

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `vtest` (
  `id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` VARCHAR(20) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT ''
) ;

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_vtest_before_ins` BEFORE INSERT ON `vtest`
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set @x=new.x;
END;
```

php:

```
    $this->db->query("replace into vtest values(1,2)");
    if ($res = $this->db->query ( "select @x as x" )) {
        while ( $obj = $res->fetch_object () ) {
                print_r($obj);
        }
        $res->close ();
    }
    $this->db->commit();
```